# I can't set the time in a date picker in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, datepicker, storyboard

I have made the following window in Xcode:

[Window for logging assingments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U96pY.jpg)

And I have written this to go along with that window

```
class logHomeworkViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var dueDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet var promptDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var homeWorkName: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let today = Date()
        homeWorkName.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nameChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        dueDatePicker.date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1,to: today)!
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        
        //set min date to midnight
        dateComponents.hour=0
        dateComponents.minute = 24
        dateComponents.day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: today)
        dateComponents.month = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: today)
        dueDatePicker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    //once due date has been chosen, allow the user to set up a reminder date
    @IBAction func dueDateChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        promptDatePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -1, to: dueDatePicker.date)
        promptDatePicker.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: Date())
        promptDatePicker.isEnabled = true
    }
    
    //once a assingment name has been set, allow input of a due date
    @objc func nameChanged(_ textField: UITextField){
        if(homeWorkName.text! != ""){
            dueDatePicker.isEnabled = true
        }else{
            dueDatePicker.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

}
```

I intend to guide the user through this window from top to bottom. As in one field has been entered the next opens up for input. Upon testing, I found that when I try to open up the date picker and set the time **after setting the assignment name**, it crashes. The logs display this after the crash `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdabb623520 terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`. Keep in mind I'm using the style of the compact date picker. This error does not occur with any another style but I need this one to work as it is best suited for my needs. This only applies to the actual time field not am or pm.

[Time entry field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kShA2.jpg)

I have narrowed down the error to the line `dueDatePicker.isEnabled = true`. When I leave the first date picker enabled by default in my storyboard and comment out the `nameChanged()` function, I get no error when attempting to set the time. I have tried to hide it instead of disabling the view but that does not work either and results in the same error. What may I have done to cause this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Note that you are not setting a default date to the DateComponents and/or the year property of DateComponents which will definitely result in an date of 2000 years ago.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. That would have probably confused me once I got past this bug.

Comment: I meant default date to the DateFormatter

Comment: Ohh. That makes more sense. I'll set it to a few days in the future or something. Is that causing the NSExeptiopn possibly?

Comment: I don’t think this is related to your error

Comment: actually you are assigning the year to the month component

Comment: Oh, wait. You are not wrong. Lmao. Let me change that. I'll see if that solves it.

Comment: That did not solve anything but thanks for pointing that out

Comment: As I said it shouldn't cause that kind of error. Make sure you have connected the outlets properly and if you have removed/renamed an outlet from your code you need also to remove it from your storyboard

Comment: Note also that what you should do is to assign the date picker as your TextField inputView and remove the editingChanged target of your TextField

Comment: Yeah. I have redone the first date picker multiple times while debugging. But like you were saying, I think all my outlets and stuff is good. I can redo it with a different variable name and picker instance though if you think that would do anything.

Comment: right-click your TextField in your storyboard and make sure there is only one connection with the right name. Again what you need is to set your date picker as your TextField `inputView`

Comment: That did it. I screwed around in the sent actions and cleared it out. For some reason leaving the only connection in the code and not in the storyboard did the trick